# Failed to resolve: junit:junit: 4.12, even though no such code line exists

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin

I have deleted the code line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`, still I am getting this error while running the Gradle sync.

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bankarpranit26.myapplication002"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The code line is not present, even then I am getting this error.

I am also getting the following errors:

```
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12

Error:Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1

Error:Error:Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2

Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1

Error:Error:line (26)Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0

Error:Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3

Error:Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3

Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
```

I am unable to understand the cause of this. Please help.

Comment: You should replace that `jcenter { url }` block with just `jcenter()`

Answer (score 0):

don't remove that line just add these lines in your repository and sync again

```
android {
    [...]
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    [...]
}
```

if this not work go to build>clean project
for other error you need to compile other librararies such as

```
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar'
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```